# Is there any way to install Ubuntu 22.04 on a chromebook?

Tags: system-installation

Tried to find info but websites were either outdated or not helpful. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which model of chromebook?

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on Chromebook (Google Pixelbook 2017)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017)